# Open a frame for the first time (using `emacsclient -c`) showing other buffer than *scratch*

Tags: buffers, emacsclient

I have emacs configured to start `org-agenda` automatically and show it instead of **scratch**. Like this:

```
(add-hook (quote after-init-hook)
              (lambda ()
              ;; ...
              (org-agenda-list 1)
              (delete-other-windows)))
```

However, the same trick don't works with `emacsclient`, the `org-agenda` buffer is there in the buffer list, but the **scratch** buffer is shown instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Startup-Summary.html) for `initial-buffer-choice`

> If non-`nil`, this variable is a string that specifies a file or directory for Emacs to display after starting up, instead of the startup screen. If its value is a function, Emacs calls that function which must return a buffer which is then displayed. If its value is `t`, Emacs displays the *scratch* buffer.

The web manual may not say it, but `C-h v` for me clarifies that this also affects emacsclient use with no target file.

So you can just set this to a function that returns the org agenda buffer.

```
(setq initial-buffer-choice '(lambda () (get-buffer org-agenda-buffer-name)))
```

Notice that, with this solution, you don't need the after-init-hook.  Just call `org-agenda-list` sometime in your init file to ensure the buffer is available for the initial choice.

Comment: if no org-agenda-list buffer exists, it opens *\*scratch\** anyway, so, this solution works well for me!

Answer (score 2):

The simple solution I have, is calling emacsclient plus some lisp evaluation. For example: `emacsclient -c -e '(switch-to-buffer "init.el")'`

You'll have to replace *init.el* by the buffer you want to open. That one suppose the init.el buffer was already launched and exists with the emacs server.

**EDIT**

Now, if using emacsclient, you want to launch the org-agenda-list function: `emacsclient -c -e '(org-agenda-list)'`

Comment: This is good, but it creates the buffer if it doesn't exists, but just one *\*Org Agenda\** buffer will be created don't matter how many times `org-agenda-list` is executed, so this may not be a big deal after all.

Comment: @JorgeArayaNavarro I thought the org-agenda-list buffer was already launched with the emacs server. Check my edits.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a function to the `after-make-frame-functions` variable.

```
after-make-frame-functions is a variable defined in `frame.el'.

Documentation:
Functions to run after a frame is created.
The functions are run with one arg, the newly created frame.
```

Comment: Does that variable affects the `C-x 5 2` command too? I don't need to watch the org-agenda on those situations where I'm creating a new frame from another frame

Comment: I assume it does affect `C-x 5 2` as well, yes. You may want to look for other options then.